# cakephp 1.2 GET URL PARAMETER

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.2

development03/carts/listview/cat_id:5

I want to receive the cat_id, which is 5. I am using $this->params['catId']) to get the cat_id. However, i got this error below

Notice (8): Undefined index: catId [APP/controllers/categories_controller.php, line 384]

**Controller**

```
function getCategoryName() {

Debugger::dump($this->params['catId']);

return $this->Category->find('all', array('conditions'=>array('Category.id' => $this->params['catId'] )));
}
```

**View**

```
<?php 

$categories = $this->requestAction("/categories/getCategoryName");
foreach ($categories as $category) {
echo $category['Category']['name'];
} ?>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think  you are looking for `$this->params['named']['catId']`

EDIT:

Apparently, in cakephp 1.2, it's `$this->passedArgs['catId']`

From the [docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#named-parameters)

Comment: Hi i tried that before. It doesn't work as well. Notice (8): Undefined index: catId [APP/controllers/categories_controller.php, line 384]

Code

    function getCategoryName() {
        
        Debugger::dump($this->params['named']['catId']);

Comment: Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'carts', 'action' => 'index')); Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display')); Router::connect('/tests', array('controller' => 'tests', 'action' => 'index'));

Comment: @do i need to declare anything at my route? appreciate your help.

Comment: @user1533321 not as far as I'm concerned :s... Could you do `var_dump($this->params)` to see if you can find where `catId` is?

Comment: i don't see any catId. this is the result i got for var_dump($this->params)... array(12) { ["pass"]=> array(0) { } ["named"]=> array(0) { } ["controller"]=> string(10) "categories" ["action"]=> &string(15) "getCategoryName" ["plugin"]=> NULL ["form"]=> array(0) { } ["url"]=> array(1) { ["url"]=> string(27) "/categories/getCategoryName" } ["autoRender"]=> int(0) ["return"]=> int(1) ["bare"]=> int(1) ["requested"]=> int(1) ["isAjax"]=> bool(false) }

Comment: hey thanks! i tried this methods as well. it doesn't work. hence i have no choice and came over to this forum to seek help.. Notice (8): Undefined index: catId [APP/controllers/categories_controller.php, line 384]

Code

    function getCategoryName() {
        
        Debugger::dump($this->passedArgs['catId']);

CategoriesController::getCategoryName() - APP/controllers/categories_controller.php, line 384
Object::requestAction() - CORE/cake/libs/object.php, line 99
include - APP/views/elements/products.ctp, line 9
...
null

Comment: is it because i am using $this->requestAction in the .ctp page. hence $this->passedArgs['catId'] doesn't work? it seems that it can't read or recognise url parameter even it show on the address bar development03/carts/listview/cat_id:5 ... got this error Notice (8): Undefined index: cat_id  or catId